# li elements act as an anchor in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code like below in my html

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="no-bullet " onclick="window.location = 'ask_question.html';">
   <button type="button" class="signout_btn line_height">
     <i class="fa fa-home " aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Home</button>
 </li>

 <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-tags" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Search by Category</a>
        <ul class="" id="loadCategories">
          <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
        </ul>
 </li>

 <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             Switch City </a>
       <ul class="" id="loadCities">
          <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bangalore</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
       </ul>
 </li> 

 <li class="no-bullet " onclick="window.location = 'user_profile.html';" >
   <button type="button" class="settings_btn line_height">
     <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
           My Profile</button>
 </li>

 <li class="no-bullet " onclick="window.location= 'all_users.html';">
   <button type="button" class="signout_btn line_height" id="btnFindAFriend">
     <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Find A Friend</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

If you notice the above code, I have `li` which on click I am directing to a certain html page. Inside the `li` I have put a button there in order to make all my menu option look uniform. In order to achieve that I did some make and break to make it look exact similar.

But I am unable to make all of them look exactly the same. I want to have the same height and size of all the menu option.

Can someone recommend a correct way to solve this.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj5ho8kL/1/) for the same.

Comment: .line_height {
    line-height: 28px;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #5d7da9;
}  *apply this*

Comment: How will this help? This will not work..

Comment: Not a fix but I think bootstrap has this to cover up: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Furthermore, I quite don't get what you want in your post. A bit to clarify

Comment: See, All I need is the height of all the menu option be of same size, If you close the menu option search by category and switch city option, you'll understand that all the buttons have the same size(height) but the other two menu options are looking different..

Comment: adding a simple css property of height & width in terms of % would solve the problem ? or i misread your question ?

Comment: Well, tbh I am fully confused with that @venkatkrishnan
That's why I thought I'd put here..

Comment: okay. if i assume it right you want something like all the menu items should look similar ? 
so, by default the height remains same. You need to fix the width. So provide with as something like 30%, "width:30%" and check did you get the expected result